# How to convert a string of array value to perform math operation in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am getting an array value after an operation.

```
let data = formula.map(a => typeof a === 'number' ? result[index++] : a)
```

My output that I am getting is

```
data=["6.9","+","7.1","-","3.0"]
```

I wanted to perform normal math operation on this data like 6.9+7.1-3.0 so my end output will be

```
endresult = 11
```

Comment: `eval(data.join(''))` although there is security risk associated to it. please refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!

Comment: What math operations do you consider normal? addition, subtraction, multiplication, divsion and modulus? `+, - * / %`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval` and pass a string into it. To create a string from the array you can use `join()`.

```js
var data=["6.9","+","7.1","-","3.0"];

var data1=["6.9","+","7.1","*","3.0"];

console.log(eval(data.join('')));
console.log(eval(data1.join('')));
```